# Counterexample to a lemma about modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

Let R be a ring with identity and not necessarily commutative. Let $M_1, M_2$ be left $R$-modules with submodules $S_1, S_2$ respectively such that $M_1/S_1 \cong M_2$ and $M_2/S_2 \cong M_1.$ Is it necessarily true that $M_1\cong M_2$ ? What if we also assume the modules are finitely generated?

It is true in the vector space case when $R$ is a field, but I doubt it remains true generally. Can someone help me find a counterexample?

Comment: This fails for infinitely generated Abelian groups: consider $M_1$ the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $M_2=M_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then we can get $M_1$ from $M_2$ by quotienting out the torsion and $M_2$ from $M_1$ by quotienting out by $2\mathbb{Z}$ on one of the coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask if epi-equivalent modules are isomorphic. You find sufficient conditions in the paper [Correct classes of modules](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/adm_correct.pdf) by R. Wisbauer. But it fails in general, for example $R/I \oplus R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ has an epimorphism to $R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, which has an epimorphism to $R/I \oplus R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}^+} \cong R/I \oplus R^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, but (usually) they are not isomorphic.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you tell me a counterexample where $M_i$ are finitely generated? After a skim through tt is not clear to me if it is addressed in the paper, so if you happen to have an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hopfian modules are epi-correct (the composition $M_1 \to M_2 \to M_1$ is an epimorphism, hence an isomorphism when $M_1$ is Hopfian, in particular $M_1 \to M_2$ is a monomorphism and therefore an isomorphism). In particular finitely generated modules over commutative rings are epi-correct. I don't want to think about noncommutative rings.

Comment: Haha fair enough. Thanks for all your help Martin.